# Can't display Codeigniter validation error

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

Don't get this. 
I have to validate basic form. Im using CI form_validation library, form validation rules are set just to "required"...if form validation fails it just need to echo validation error in login form. Im using by default `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` Helper is autoloaded. Form functionality is OK it works how it should, only problem is that framework dont display error messagges if dont fill required fields?

login_form.php - VIEW

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?> 

<?php echo form_input('email' , 'email'); ?> <br>
<?php echo form_input('password' , 'password'); ?> <br>
<?php echo form_submit('submit' , 'submit'); ?>
```

login.php - CONTROLLER

```
<?php
Class Login extends CI_Controller {

  function index () {
    $data ['content'] = "login_form";
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
  }

  function validate() {
    $this->load->library("form_validation");


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email' , 'email' , 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'password' , 'md5|trim|required');

    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('login/index');
    }
    else {
        redirect("user/profile");
    }
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please paste your controller and view

Comment: redirect('login/index'); dont use redirect load your view

Comment: Here is full code.

Comment: or you can try your code just comment out  redirect('login/index'); and place <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> you will see errors if there are any

Comment: It is not  view, it is another controller and method that loads profile view... so it is not bug.

Comment: yes it is not view but when you will redirect from this controller you will not able to print errors. You can simple load your view if validation goes false

Comment: I do not see any form_open() on view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use code in controller like this hope will help you just set form action to login.php
**login.php - CONTROLLER**

```
function index () {
    $data ['content'] = "login_form";
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email' , 'email' , 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'password' , 'md5|trim|required');
    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
          $this->load->view("template", $data);
    }
    else {
        redirect("user/profile");
     }  
}
```

**login_form.php - VIEW**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?> 

<?php echo form_input('email' , 'email'); ?> <br>
<?php echo form_input('password' , 'password'); ?> <br>
<?php echo form_submit('submit' , 'submit'); ?>
```

Comment: @goran, note that instead of redirecting, the page view is simply reloaded. When you redirect all the data in the current page is lost - including the `form_validation` class and all of its data. Look carefully at the [form validation documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) examples. You will see it done the same way. The above is the correct answer.

Comment: @Farhan is only usually `==` not `===` in run part

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    redirect('login/index');
}
```

Don't redirect, else error will not be available. Instead of that keep

```
if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $data ['content'] = "login_form";
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
}
```

Check the following link for more details: 
[Form Validation : CodeIgniter User Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#helperreference)